# Upgrading and Reverting .msi

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

While working with my deployment project for my outlook add-in, I've had to rebuild the msi a more than a couple of times. I was wondering what the best practices are for upgrading my installed msi as well as reverting to older versions.

I've written a lot of different batch files to handle the job, but none of them seem like the best way to complete this task. Currently I have two batch files, one to upgrade and the other to revert.

To upgrade all I do is either change the product code or change the version number and the product code. Then I run the simple command `myapplication.msi /quiet`. This works because of the change of product code and version number, though the version number can remain the same and switch the setup to not detect newer versions. Otherwise I get the "Another version of this product is already installed." error

To revert, I have the following command: `C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /quiet /x myapplication.msi` followed by the one above with the previous version name (usually `prevmyapplication.msi`). This is working fine, but it feels that there's probably a better way.

Thanks for any help in direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The by the book answer is that you are doing it the correct way. Microsoft has asserted that allowing "downgrades" is not the expected user behavior and that one must do an uninstall / reinstall to do so.

I've used a pattern where we intentionally allow downgrades.  The reason is so operations has an easier go at it.  The SCCM advertisement that takes you from 1.0 to 2.0 can also take you from 3.0 to 2.0.   There is a downside though that if operations messes up and has multiple, conflicting advertisements you can get a tug of war.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with SCCM, is this similar to VS deployment projects? I've done a little looking into what it is and I don't think I've used this before.

Comment: If you have a VS setup project, then I assume you have RemovePreviousVersions=True, but what about DetectNewerInstalledVersions? How is that set?

Comment: SCCM is Microsoft Systems Center Configuration Manager. It's a tool that takes your MSI and distributes it to thousands of machines.

Comment: @PhilDW I have RemovePreviousVersion=True and  DetectNewerInstalledVersions=False

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I'll contact my IT people to see if we use SCCM.

Comment: There are other tools similar to SCCM.  They all do basically the same thing.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter So, there isn't an easy way to allow previous versions without using some sort of tool or doing what I'm currently doing, is that correct?